# Add a transparent color layer above a background image

Tags: css

I need to add a transparent coloured layer over a background image. I tried doing this with rgba but with no result.

What I get now is:

```
page-heading {
    background: rgba(36, 70, 105, 0.74) url("../images/samples/bg3.jpg") no-repeat fixed 50% 0px / cover;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 72px 0px;
}
```

I know that the background color is a fallback for when the image cannot be loaded. How do I add a layer over it in a correct way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a simple `box-shadow` inset:

```
.page-heading {
    background: url(../images/samples/bg3.jpg) no-repeat fixed 50% 0px / cover;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100px rgba(36, 70, 105, 0.74);
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/q0cLf2s7/

Comment: What did you said "chapuza" in english?

Comment: What do you mean @MarcosPérezGude ?

Comment: Maybe this works apparently for you, but is the weirdest way to make this, and in spanish we said "chapuza". In english, reffered by google translate, it said botched job

Comment: Oh alright. Yeah it works for me, maybe it's not the best solution but I got no problems with it, it works, also on all phones etc.

Comment: Yeah, you can use it. But make a background above another background with a box-shadow it's not the best way (see that the 4th parameter is 1000px!!) . If it fits with your requirements use it!!

Comment: Actually, the 1000px can be changed to the size that you need. Updated with 100px instead of 1000px.

Answer (score 8):

I see that a lot of people here create an extra element or pseudo elements, but **you don't need two elements** to create this effect. You can simply declare two background-images. One of which is the original image, and the other a linear gradient. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GustvandeWal/ypkhjqe5/) to see the effect working.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(36,70,105,.74), rgba(36,70,105,.74)),
      url("https://dummyimage.com/1000x1000/3/f.png&text=Background-image");
```

Note that you first have to declare the gradient and then the image (I always get this wrong the first time I try to make this)

Comment: Thanks, this is also a short solution. I already got it working with a boxshadow though.

Comment: That's a good solution, but only compatible with browsers that supports multple backgrounds. This is better solution than box-shadow

Comment: In this answer, there aren't any additional elements added. That's the point of my answer: keeping it clean.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a gradient like the fiddle below.

The left is the original image. The right is the one with the gradient applied.

```css
.block   {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.og  {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300);
}

.ed  {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)), url(http://placehold.it/300x300);
}
```

```html
<div class="block og"></div>
<div class="block ed"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a pseudo element...

```css
.page-heading {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200") no-repeat fixed 50% 0px / cover;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 72px 0px;
}

.page-heading:before {
    content: "";
    background: rgba(36, 70, 105, 0.74);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-heading">
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pseudo-element to place over your . This way you won't use an extra DOM element.

```
.element {
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/500/500/');
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

.element:after {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/volzy/LLfhm0kc/1/

Answer (score -1):

```
body{
background-color: #ccc;
margin:0px;
```

}

```
.page-heading {
background: rgba(36, 70, 105, 0.74);
opacity: 0.4;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
width:100%;
height:100vh;
text-align: center;
padding: 72px 0px;
```

}

I use body but the element could be something else
Hi, here a fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/5f46znzx/

is what you are looking for?

remember that opacity trasform each element with the opacity set.
i suggest to eliminate it if you dont need that internal element takes opacity.

Answer (score -2):

You need another box above the header. Imagine that's your HTML:

```
<div class="page-heading">
   <div class="page-heading-fake">
   </div>
</div>
```

You can have this CSS

```
.page-heading {
    background: url(yourimg.png);
    position: relative; /* neccesary to make an anchor in the fake */
}
.page-heading-fake {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color:  rgba(36, 70, 105, 0.74) ;
}
```

Comment: And people, when you need to answer answer by yourself, don't edit my answers

Comment: I would imagine the down votes are because you are unnecessarily adding another element. Your rude comments on another answer probably didn't help either.

Comment: The rude comments came after the downvote. Create a new element is no reason to downvote. Leave in blank the votes. That's a solution, if fits to op requirements is good, if not that's ok too. But this works, it's not reason to downvote

Comment: I edited your answer because it had an error! Is that a problem?